# How to use ldap when working with nfs shares for the home directory?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, nfs, home-directory

Recently I setup a ldap server within my network.  I'm looking to connect all of my linux machines to it however before I proceed I need to figure out a few things.

I plan on mounting an nfs share to my san for all home folders and want to call it /homes/  so when creating the ldap account I will then create them a folder for their home directories.

With that said do I have to have the san attached to ldap so that i can set the owner of that folder to the user or should I have root own the /home/ folder but allow the user to r/w/x anything inside so they can create whatever they want?

If I don't connect the nfs to ldap can I do a chown 10000:100000?  as in the user and group id instead of the name?

Also I notice when i create a local account on my ubuntu machines I get a user of dave and a group of dave.  Is this a convention or is a user of dave and a group of users sufficient?  I haven't been able to find good documentation on standard practices when it comes to the structure of ldap and how to setup home directories.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly "set the owner of that folder to the user".

You will need to setup your ldap.conf and nssswitch to work with LDAP.
Then, the users which will not be created on the linux machines, will have posix attributes within LDAP that will allow you to set the homeDirectory, the primary group (which certainly can be different than the user).

We do a lot of work with various organizations and have provided some information on [LDAP for Linux and Unix Clients](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDAP%20for%20Linux%20and%20Unix%20Clients)

-jim